# can anyone explain this code of media controller?

Tags: android

can anyone explain this code of media controller?

```
   videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.player);
   videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName()+ "/" +R.raw.sample));
   videoview.start();

  MediaController controller = new MediaController(this);
  controller.setMediaPlayer(videoview);
  videoview.setMediaController(controller);
```

Comment: you are setting the mediacontroller object to your videoview

Answer (score 0):

The code gets a VideoView by its id, sets the uri of the file to play to an embedded resource and starts playback.

Then it attaches a MediaController to the view which renders the progress bar and some controls to play / pause the video.

Comment: can u pls explain these lines in detail   ... controller.setMediaPlayer(videoview);
  videoview.setMediaController(controller);